# Having a problem factoring a quadratic

Tags: quadratics, factoring

$15x^2-4x-4$, 
I factored it out to this:
$$5x(3x-2)+2(3x+2).$$
But I don’t know what to do next since the twos in the brackets have opposite signs, or is it still possible to factor them out?

Comment: You should have a $-2$ in the second parentheses.

Comment: Wellcome to math.stackexchange! Please make use of MathJax so as to make it easier for the community to read and answer your questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the linear term of $15x^2 - 4x - 4$, you must find two numbers with product $15 \cdot (-4) = -60$ and sum $-4$.  They are $-10$ and $6$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
15x^2 - 4x - 4 & = 15x^2 - 10x + 6x - 4 && \text{split the linear term}\\
               & = 5x(3x - 2)  + 2(3x - 2) && \text{factor by grouping}\\
               & = (5x + 2)(3x - 2)  && \text{extract the common factor}
\end{align*}
You made a sign error while extracting the factor of $2$ from $6x - 4$.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be $-2$:
$$15x^2-4x-4 = 5x(3x-2)+2(3x-2) = (5x+2)(3x-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$15x^2-4x-4=15x^2-10x+6x-4=5x(3x-2)+2(3x-2)=(5x+2)(3x-2).$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you made an arithmetic mistake. I got $$15x^2-4x-4=(5x+2)(3x-2)=5x(x-2)+2(3x-2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$15x^2-4x-4=15x^2-10x+6x-4=5x(3x-2)+2(3x-2)=(5x+2)(3x-2)$$

You probably missed a sign! ;)